# How to retrieve values of nested dictionaries as a json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a very long json file that starts with
{"requestId": "2",
"records": {
"totalRecords": 5,
"currentPageSize": 5,
"currentPageNumber": 1 ...
I uploaded the file to a variable with data = files.upload()
Google Colab tells me that the file is already a dictionary, so I belive I don't have to use loads to turn it into one.
I want to print the value assosciated with records, so I believe I should do data.get("requestID").get("records") but thats gets me 'bytes has no attributes 'get'.

Additionally when printing data I get

{'calls_data (1).json': b'{\n  "requestId": "2",\n  "records": {\n    "totalRecords": 5,\n    "currentPageSize": 5,\n    "currentPageNumber": 1\ ...

which starts with 'calls_data(1).json' as a key for some reason?
i am confused

Answer (score 0):

When you upload files using `files.upload()`, you get a dictionary whose keys are the names of the files you uploaded, and whose values are the contents of those files in bytes. In order to access the fields inside your uploaded JSON, you'll need to call `json.loads`, for example:

```py
>>> from google.colab import files
>>> file_contents = files.upload() # here you upload 'calls_data (1).json'
>>> data = json.loads(file_contents['calls_data (1).json'])
>>> print(data.get('requestID').get('records'))
{'totalRecords': 5, 'currentPageSize': 5, ...}
```